# Printing value of sql.NullString in Go template

Tags: sql, go, struct, go-templates

I have fetched details from database where couple of column were of `sql.NullString` and `sql.NullInt64` column.

Now, while I print them, after checking if it is `Valid`, it prints data in `{3 true}` format. I only want to print value `3` from it.

How can I achieve this?

Currently this is what, I am printing:

```
{{ range $value := .CatMenu }}
   ... // Other data
   {{ $value.ParentID }}  // This is sql.NullInt64 type
{{ end }}
```

Comment: Then print only the `Int64` field of it, not the entire `NullInt64` value. Show us how you use it or print it if you still have trouble with it.

Comment: How to print only `Int64` field of it. Currently, I am printing as mentioned in above :- `$value.ParentID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sql.NullInt64`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullInt64) is a struct:

```
type NullInt64 struct {
    Int64 int64
    Valid bool // Valid is true if Int64 is not NULL
}
```

When printing struct values, the default formatting is what you currently see.

If you check if it is valid and non-`nil` prior, you can simply print the `NullInt64.Int64` field only which holds the numerical value.

This is how you can do it:

```
{{ range $value := .CatMenu }}
   ... // Other data
   {{ $value.ParentID.Int64 }}  // This is sql.NullInt64 type
{{ end }}
```

See this simple example to test it:

```
vs := []*sql.NullInt64{
    {3, true},
    {2, true},
}

t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(
    "{{range .}}{{.Int64}}\n{{end}}",
))

if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, vs); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ICWKOcrLwC)):

```
3
2
```